# How to redirect user to current url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to redirect user to the same `url` of the page.

I know that `window.location.href = 'custom_url';` will redirect to a `custom_url`.

But I need to redirect him, to the same page that he's already in.

So how to do that with jQuery?

Comment: why dont just reload the page with `window.location.reload()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to refresh current page:

```
location.reload();
```

```js
console.log("loaded");
```

```html
<button onclick="location.reload();">Refresh Page </button>
```

Or by click via jQuery:

```
$('#something').click(function() {
    location.reload();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the thing you could do is using

```
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```

it ***may*** take some time more than usual to read and change the href.

you can also use

```
location.replace(window.location.href);
```

using this, when you check your history,
you will not see the site reloaded many times *(I am using chrome)*.

and you can also use

```
location.assign("/");
```

.